# Are there any conventions for aggregating multiple errors as the causes of another error?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm writing a function that iterates over a vector of `Result` and returns success if they all were successful, or an error if any failed. Limitations in `error::Error` are frustrating me and I'm not sure how to work around them. Currently I have something like:

```
let mut errors = Vec::new();            

for result in results {                             
     match result {                        
         Err(err) => errors.push(err),
         Ok(success) => { ... }
     }                                                                                                                                      
}

if errors.is_empty() {
    return Ok(())
else {
    return Err(MyErrorType(errors))
}
```

The problem with my current approach is that I can only set one error to be the `cause` of `MyErrorType`, and my error's `description` needs to be a static `String` so I can't include the descriptions of each of the triggering failures. All of the failures are potentially relevant to the caller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no convention that I know of, and indeed I have never had the issue of attempting to report multiple errors at once...

... that being said, there are two points that may help you:

1. There is no limitation that the description be a `'static` `String`, you are likely confusing `&'static str` and `&str`. In `fn description(&self) -> &str`, the lifetime of `str` is linked to the lifetime of `self` (lifetime elision) and therefore an embedded `String` satisfies the constraints
2. `Error` is an interface to deal with errors uniformly. In this case, indeed, only a single `cause` was foreseen, however it does not preclude a more specific type to aggregate multiple causes and since `Error` allows downcasting (`Error::is`, `Error::downcast`, ...) the more specific type can be retrieved by the handler and queried in full

As such, I would suggest that you create a new concrete type solely dedicated to holding multiple errors (in a `Vec<Box<dyn Error>>`), and implementing the `Error` interface. It's up to you to decide on the description and cause it will expose.

A single type will let your clients test more easily for downcasting than having an unknown (and potentially growing as time goes) number of potential downcast targets.

Answer (score 3):

expanding a bit on point 1 of Matthieu's good answer.
The point where you're likely running into trouble (I know I did when I tried to implement `Error`) is that you want to have a dynamic `description()`.

```
// my own error type
#[derive(Debug)] struct MyError { value: u8 }

impl fmt::Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            write!(f, "bummer! Got a {}", self.value)
    }
}

// I am now tempted to add the problematic value dynamically
// into the description, but I run into trouble with lifetimes 
// this DOES NOT COMPILE because the String I'm building
// goes out of scope and I can't return a reference to it
impl error::Error for MyError {
   fn description(&self) -> &str {
        &format!("can't put a {} here!", self.value)
   }
}
```

**solution 1**

Don't dynamically build `description()`. Just use a static str. This is what [most implementations of Error on github](https://github.com/search?q=%22impl%20error%3A%3AError%20for%22&type=Code) seem to do.
If you need to retrieve and display (or log) the value you can always access it from your `MyError` type. Plus `Display` (that you must implement for all Error impls) does allow you to create dynamic strings.

I created a [contrived example on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=27538b7e468395d3bcc4&version=nightly) that shows how to track multiple errors.

**solution 2**

(what Matthieu is suggesting) you can store the error message in the error itself.

```
#[derive(Debug)] struct MyError { value: u8, msg: String }

impl MyError {
    fn new(value: u8) -> MyError {
        MyError { value: value, msg: format!("I don't like value {}", value) }
    }
}

// now this works because the returned &str has the same lifetime
// as self
impl error::Error for MyError {
   fn description(&self) -> &str {
        &self.msg
    }
}
```